# Momentjs / Angularjs - Checking if 2 dates are in the same period - TimeSheet project

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, momentjs

I am working on a simple Timesheet app, I am trying to implement an auto calculator  that will sum up your hours for each day (Sunday, Monday, Tuesday, etc ...). A problem I noticed is that in some cases, users will enter activities that will be within the same date time periods.

For example:

```
$scope.Example = [
{Description:"Example activity",Start:"2018-06-24 8:00",End:"2018-06-24 10:00",Total:2},
{Description:"Example activity2",Start:"2018-06-24 9:00",End:"2018-06-24 10:00",Total:1},
{Description:"Example activity3",Start:"2018-06-24 10:00",End:"2018-06-24 11:00",Total:1}];

$scope.Calculate_all_entries = function(){

    $scope.Total.Sunday = 0;

    if($scope.Example){

        angular.forEach($scope.Example, function(element){

            if(moment(element.Start).format("dddd") === "Sunday"){

                $scope.Total.Sunday = $scope.Total.Sunday + element.Total;

            }

        })

    }

}
```

In this case the total should be 3 hours and not 4 hours as we dont charge for work within the same hours. I'm need to implement a system that would check if the dates are within the same period and provide the appropriate total.

I found this in the documentation on momentjs that seemed to be close to what i need but only takes one value:

```
moment('2010-10-19 11:00').isBetween('2010-10-19 10:00', '2010-10-25 00:00'); // true
```

Would anyone know of any other methods to check wether or not the start and end time are in the same period as other entries in the same day?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure, you can use momentjs's unix() function to convert those date times to an integer which then can easily be used to check whether the timestamp is in between two other timestamps.

Here is an example:

```
var timeToCheck = moment('2010-10-19 11:00').unix();
var startTime = moment('2010-10-19 10:00').unix();
var endTime = moment('2010-10-25 00:00').unix();
console.log(timeToCheck >= startTime && timeToCheck <= endTime); // true
```